# Menu text moves on hover

Tags: css

When I hover over the text, the text moves. The reason that the text is moving is that I remove the bold effect on hover. How to stop the text to move on hover?

```
#menu li a{
    color:#595959;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    position: relative; 
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:2px 5px;
}

#menu li a:hover{
    color:#FFFFFF;  
    font-weight:normal;
    background-color:#e11d3b;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    text-decoration:none;   
}
```

Comment: can you post the html and _all_ the css for your navigation bar?

Comment: Do you have a set width/height on the li containing them?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to show the problem?

Comment: Monospace font? http://jsfiddle.net/Y3Pwa/1/ (actually, the text still jiggles in Firefox). Have a talk with your designer. Convince him/her that bold text is nicer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only way you can avoid this is setting the `width` fixed. (of each `li` element)

If not, the `bold` will always move your text..

Answer (score 0):

Well, by being shorter without bold, it's mathematic that the text will appear to move, since it does not have the same size anymore... 
by doing something like that:

```
#menu li a{
    color:#595959;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    position: relative; 
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:2px 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    text-align:center;
}

#menu li a:hover{
    color:#FFFFFF;  
    font-weight:normal;
    background-color:#e11d3b;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

You set a width to the link, as well as a display type block (so it will behave like a div for instance). This way, you can add a text-align: center; that will minimize the impression the text has moved.

Comment: I cannot give width to li. Menu text has a diferent size.

Comment: for the font-size, it was just to improve the size of the text to make the problem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css `#menu li a:hover{padding:2px 5px 2px 6px;}`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abdulmalik/KALzk/)